# jQuery Countdown plugin countdown only seconds

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, countdown, countdowntimer, jquery-countdown

I am using the [Jquery Countdown Plugin](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) and would like to only countdown in seconds and add the total time in seconds.

For example, when my countdown is 10 minutes, instead of showing 
9 minutes 59 seconds and counting, it would show 599 seconds and counting.
Is this possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#yourElement').countdown({
    until: someTime,
    format: 'S' // <-- the magic is happening here
});
```

The relevant documentation [is found here](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) (Tab: Formats 2, 4th example)